# Create dynamic playlist in ffmpeg

Tags: video, cmd, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to stream videos countinuously so I create this playlist (test.txt)

file 'test1.mp4'

file 'test2.mp4'

file 'test3.mp4'

and I use this command in ffmpeg to run playlist

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -i test.txt -b:v 2.5M -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=188&buffer_size=3M
```

But is there a way to add files to run after this playlist without interrupt streaming or Make the process moves to another playlist When the first one ends

I am looking for any way to stream other movies after playlist finish during the process running (without interrupt streaming)

please help me

Comment: The only way is to write your own demuxer.

Comment: is there any example to explain that ?

Comment: The concat demuxer is a good start